# Is there an easy way to find parameter by three information?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

$f(x)=a+b.c^x$ and we know 
$$f(0)=15\\
f(2)=30\\f(4)=90$$
so put down point in function and have:
$$a+b.1=15\\a+b.c^2=30\\a+b.c^4=90$$so $$(2)-(1) \to bc^2-b=30-15\\(3)-(2) \to bc^4-bc^2=90-30\\b(c^2-1)=15\\bc^2(c^2-1)=60 \to \div\\
\frac{bc^2(c^2-1)}{b(c^2-1)}=\frac{60}{15}\\c^2=4\\c=\pm 2 \\\ \to c=+2\to  a=10,b=5$$
Is there was a way to find $a,b,c$  easier or by other method ,for example using logarithm ...?

Comment: Your method looks like it was very effective and not too slow to find the answer.

Comment: That's probably the best way, yeah.

Comment: @Khosrotash Why did you choose $c=+2$?

Comment: @Karlo If $c$ is not positive then $c^x$ is not defined for all real numbers. For example, $(-2)^{1/2}=\sqrt{-2}.$